# How do I call a JSON web service from PHP with parameters and callback?

Tags: php, json, web-services, curl, callback

I call a webservice from a JQuery $.getJSON function, it works fine.

```
    var p = {
       'field1': 'value1',
       'field2': 'value2',
       'field3': 'value3'
    };

    $.getJSON('https://service:xxx@xxx.xxx.yyyyy.com.xx/service/search?callback=?', p, function(data) {
    if (data[0]) {      
        // print results
    } else  {
        // no results found
    }
});
```

I am trying to connect from PHP and CURL, however it does not work, it always return false.

//FIRST TRY

```
$params = array(  'field1' => 'value1',  'field2' => 'value2', 'field3'=> 'value3');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://service:xxx@xxx.xxx.yyyyy.com.xx/service/search?callback=?');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
$result = curl_exec($ch); // return false instead of my JSON
```

// SECOND TRY

```
    $data_string = json_encode($params);                                                                                   
    $ch = curl_init('https://https://service:xxx@xxx.xxx.yyyyy.com.xx/service/search?callback=?');                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

    $result2 = curl_exec($ch); //return false instead of my JSON
```

What I am doing wrong?

many thanks,

Comment: is the request jsonp or json?  The format of what's returned is different in both cases

Comment: .getJSON is a get request. In PHP you are using a post request. Also in POSTFIELDS takes an associative array but in your second try you only gave it a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to this:

```
$params = array(  'field1' => 'value1',  'field2' => 'value2', 'field3'=> 'value3');

$data_string = implode('&',$params);
//NB: you may need to urlencode the each of your params

$ch = curl_init('https://service:xxx@xxx.xxx.yyyyy.com.xx/service/search?  callback=?&' .$data_string);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
$result2 = curl_exec($ch);
```

Untested code, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery request is using GET.  The curl code you wrote appears to be sending a post request (i'm not an expert in curl).  Obviously the receiving server handles different types of requests differently, so make sure you send a get via curl and that should help.

Answer (score 0):

getJSON sends a GET request, so you need to convert params array to a string with http_build_query and append it to query. As you're requesting the data with HTTPS you need to point CURL to valid cerficate with CURLOPT_CAINFO / CURLOPT_CAPATH, i'll just ignore the validation in the code.

```
$params = array(  'field1' => 'value1',  'field2' => 'value2', 'field3'=> 'value3');
$url = 'https://service:xxx@xxx.xxx.yyyyy.com.xx/service/search?callback=?' . http_build_query($params);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if($result === FALSE) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
```